# Implementing Stripe with React-native and Django

Tags: django, react-native, stripe-payments

I am using React-native for mobile app and Django as server. How to implement stripe payment gateway? How I can make a payment and send the response to the backend so that in backend I can handle which user is now subscribed?

In web we can do that using stripe-session url. We can hit the url and after successful payment it's return an id, I have to just post the id to the server.

How can I do that with react-native because by doing so I am kicked out from my app and the session url opens in the browser, i can make the payment successfully but cannot redirect to the app.
How to successfully I can implement this with react-native and django?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network), React Native provides the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).  You should be able to make POST requests to your Django back-end that way.

You may run into issues with authentication (since Django POST request require CSRF tokens).  There are many docs about this topic and you should be able to find a solution that meets your needs with a few searches.

As for how to implement your Stripe payment flow, that depends on how you want to collect payment details for your subscriptions.  Stripe public docs have many useful examples from using a Stripe hosted [Checkout page](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions), using Stripe [Payment Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements), or using the basic [Quickstart](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart) example to get you started.  The Python back-end uses Flask instead of Django but it is not difficult to understand how to translate the functionality from one framework to another.

As a back-up and general best practice, consider utilizing [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to ensure your back-end is aware of changes to Stripe records. Financial networks include many asynchronous processes and it's a good idea to not just rely on the Request <-> Response loop.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually I know about the fetch api, the problem I am facing is that, after successful payment stripe will give me some response, should I post this response to server and am I able to check is the user is subscribed or not based on the response stripe provide after successful payment?..